# Select from a drop down list, options in a second drop down list

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm new to this forum, and really hope somebody could help me, as I've been searching Google endlessly the last few days.

I'm writing an app where you can choose a location, ex. grocery store, petrol station, and also a scenario like asking if you can pay by card.
The scenario then gets translated to another language.

What I'm trying to accomplish is the following:

I would like to select a location from a drop down list, which in turn would give me options for that selection in a second drop down list.

Example:

```
SELECT grocery store FROM first drop down
```

The second drop down must populate with scenarios that you would use in a grocery store

```
SELECT petrol station FROM first drop down
```

The second drop down must populate with scenarios that you would use at petrol station.

I will post my code, if needed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally got it right.

```
listPlaces = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spnPlaces);
    listScenarios = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spnScenario);
    String[] places = new String[] {"At the Supermarket","At the Petrol Station", "At The Spur"};       

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, places);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    listPlaces.setAdapter(adapter);

    listPlaces.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            switch (position){
            case 0:{
                List <String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
                list.add("Tea");
                list.add("Coffee");
                list.add("Sugar");
                list.add("Milk");
                ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Options.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, list);
                dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                listScenarios.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
                break;
            }
            case 1:{
                List <String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
                list.add("Bread");
                list.add("Butter");
                list.add("Eggs");
                list.add("Bacon");
                ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Options.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, list);
                dataAdapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                dataAdapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();
                listScenarios.setAdapter(dataAdapter2);
                break;
                }
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Attach a select listener on your first combo in which you will fill the select options for the second combo.

Comment: I've actually done that. Where I'm struggling is the next step, to populate the second spinner with the different lists, according to whats selected in the first list.